# how to get content from blade files and show in modals dynamically in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have five different modal forms with their js that are shown when their corresponding button is being clicked, which is messy to put all modals and other content in one blade file.

I want to have only one blank modal on the page which will be filled by content related to its button clicked. Is there any way I can put my five different modals form content in five different blade files and when its button is clicked on the main page I get the content from the related modal blade file and fill it in the blank modal and load its js?

Comment: can you give some example ? I couldn't get what are you trying for ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

In your controller imagine you have a method named **create** and you want to put its response into the modal body.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
class SomeController extends Controller{

  public funtion create(){
    $someVariable;
    $view=\View::make::('directory.your_blade_file',compact('someVariable'));
    return ['html'=>$view->render()];
  }
}
```

And now in your client side code you can act like this.

> **Notice:** I assume you use jQuery ajax to get data from server and bootstrap modal to show content

```
<div class="modal" id="single-modal-in-the-page" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">

  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script>
 $(function(){
   $('#some-button').on('click',function(){
      var modal=$('#single-modal-in-the-page');  
      $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:'http://url/some/create',
        data:{/*any query string paramteres can be set here*/},
        success:function(response){
          modal.find('.modal-body').html(response.html);
          modal.modal('show');
        },
        error:function(error){
          // Or handle the errors in your own way
          console.log(error);
        }

      });    
   });
 });

</script>
```